# Infinite site model and Watterson's Estimator

Tags: population-genetics

Why is it that under migration, the watterson's estimator (theta) is upward biased? What does upward bias means? And why do we have downward bias under exponential growth? Lastly, is it only the watterson's estimator whose variance would decrease with increasing recombination rate or would the tajima's estimator's variance would decrease too?